# UIDatePicker DidSelectRow Method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know UIPickerViews use a didSelectRow method to update labels etc when a row is selected.

I have a UIDatePicker that updates a label when a row is selected and done button is pressed, but I also want a UILabel that updates with each selection, so its live updating as the user changes the date.  I can't find any method such as didSelectRow for the date picker though.  How is this possible?

```
- (IBAction)dateButtonPressed
{
    [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:dateView];

    UIBarButtonItem *acceptButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismssPickerChangeDate)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = acceptButton;
    [acceptButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(dismssPickerCancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton1;
    [cancelButton1 release];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Select Date";
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [dateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }];
    NSDate *myDate = picker.date;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    //NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d y"]; 
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]; 
    NSLog(@"New Date is = %@",dateString);
    dateLabel.text = dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

UIDatePicker is a UIControl, so use

```
[picker addTarget:yourController action:@selector(yourAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

to send a message to your controller. The controller can then get the state of the date picker and update the label.

If your picker and your label are both outlets in the same class, in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.picker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabelFromPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then create updateLabelFromPicker:

```
- (IBAction)updateLabelFromPicker:(id)sender {
    self.label.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.picker.date];    
}
```

You'll want an NSDateFormatter to make the date pretty.

Comment: Thanks Terry, Im a bit confused as what to do with "your controller".  I currently just have an outlet for the datePicker and the dateLabel I want to update realtime.

Comment: I updated it with more detail. The class you've declared your outlets in is your controller.

Comment: I have all the NSFormatter setup because I have another label that updates after the user presses done, so I just have to configure this one as real time.  Let me play with the code you posted, thanks.

Comment: hmm I can't get it setup properly, im going to post the code I'm using in my question thanks.

Comment: Is the dateButtonPressed method the method you specified in addTarget:action:forControlEvents ?

Comment: well actually I want all this to happen within the dateButtonPressed.  This method brings up the view with the datePicker and the label i want updating real time, in it.

Comment: That will only pick up the date picker's time once, not every time the picker changes. You need the picker to send a message when it changes to get the live updating.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying.  So based on the code I have currently, what did I need to change.  Can I still keep all the code in this method or must I create a new method and call that method?

Comment: You can keep that code, but move the text field updating code into a separate method that gets call by dateButtonPressed and the date picker (via addTarget:action:forControlEvents)

Comment: Ok so I'm removing the date stuff in the method I have previously and replacing it with `[self updateLabel]`  Now I'm making a method called `-(void) updateLabel;` and will include the code you listed above?

Comment: Yes, have the dateButtonPressed method call [self updateLabel] and do [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged] in viewDidLoad

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've added that to viewDidLoad and setup the updateLabel method, now I just need to fill it with the necessary code.  Is all I need in updateLabel the following: `self.label.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.picker.date];`, along with the Date formatter stuff?

Answer (score 1):

A date picker does things a little differently. From the documentation:

> When properly configured, a UIDatePicker object sends an action message when a user finishes rotating one of the wheels to change the date or time; the associated control event is UIControlEventValueChanged.

Because a UIDatePicker inherits from UIControl, you have access to all the various touch events you'd expect (TouchUpInside, etc).

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3/4

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
 {
   println("\(courseCatalog[row])")
    yourlabelname.text=courseCatalog[row]

}
```