# cancel button appears but done button does not appear in uitoolbar

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I have written the code below to display the datepicker in popover along uitoolbar.
I can see the cancel button but not the Done button.

If I remove the code for flexspace then done button appears but I need the done button to be on the extreme right positon but it stands next to cancel button.

How can I fix this ? Thanks in Advance.

```
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

     datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
    datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
    [datePicker setTag:10];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    popoverController.delegate=self;



    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.uitext.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];//tempButton.frame where you need you can put that frame




//    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,40)];
//    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
//    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
//    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//    
//    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel_clicked:)];
//    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];
//  
//    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
//    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
//  
//    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done_clicked:)];
//    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
//    
//  
//    
//    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
//    




//    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
//    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216);
//    picker.delegate  = self;
//    picker.dataSource = self;
//    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
//    [actionSheet addSubview:picker];


    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.bounds.size.width,40)];
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];


    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
        [popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];

    [self.uitext resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: have you done addSubView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.bounds.size.width,40)];
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];


    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
```

Hope it helps you..

EDIT :-

Add this line below `[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];` :-

```
pickerToolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

and comment `[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];` line

So your code will be

```
 UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.bounds.size.width,44.0)];
    //[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done_clicked:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];


    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    pickerToolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
```

Comment: I did try it still is the same I will paste the entire code including the popover

Comment: Another add-on question how do I get the date picked after tapping on done button.

Comment: Check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748752/uidatepicker-didselectrow-method. Here only from sender you have to type cast and make it as UIDatePicker and then use datePicker.date, here you will get your result