# How to set the second date picker's minimum date as first date picker's selected date and get the dates realtime in ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker

In my app there are two date picker's. for the `first date picker` view I have set the minimum date as current date like this

```
[self.firstDatePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
```

then I want to set the minimum date for the `second date picker` should be the user `selected date` `plus` one day from the `first date picker`(selected date).

```
self.secondDatePicker.minimumDate = @"some thing"
```

- how can I do that and the other thing is I want to get the changed date real time(like picker view, that means we can get the  changed item value real time. so is it possible with this. ).

help me wit this.

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748752/uidatepicker-didselectrow-method), just replace the action with your `setMinimumDate ` for 2nd picker then done

Comment: yep, it helped me for others I put it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did, and [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748752/uidatepicker-didselectrow-method) helped me with this.

```
self.datepickerOne.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
    [self.datepickerOne addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateFromPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

above I Set the minimum date for the first `date picker`.
and after that get the selected date from the first `datepicker`

for that use this action method to update the selected date and at the same time I set the minimum date for the `seconddate picker`

```
- (IBAction)updateDateFromPicker:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.datepickerOne.date);
    self.datepickerTwo.minimumDate = [self.datepickerOne.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:24*60*60];
}
```

hope this will help to others also.